# WooCommerce: Get multiple specific product attributes with attribute label

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display a set of specific product attributes on the product details page. Like this:

- **Colors:** blue, red
- **Sizes**: M, L, XL

Until now I only found a code to show every attribute of a product:

```
global $product;
    $attribute = $product->get_attributes();
    
    $attribute_arr = array();
    
    if( count($attribute) > 0 ){
        foreach ($attribute as $key => $value) {
            $attribute_arr[] = $key;
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that I dont want to show all of them. Only a specific set of attributes.
Maybe I could use a array to define the attributes I want to show. Something like:

```
array('pa_color', 'pa_size')
```

I also have a working code to show a specific attribute:

```
<?php
global $product;
$pa_colors = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_color', array( 'fields' =>  'all', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) );
if( $pa_colors ) : ?>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $pa_colors as $pa_color ) : ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $pa_color->name; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
        
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a way to combine these two codes?
And how could I show the label (e.g. color) for the attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use instead the WordPress `wp_get_post_terms()` function as follow:

```
global $product;

$attribute_taxonomies = array('pa_colors', 'pa_sizes'); // Defined product attribute taxonomies

// Loop through your defined product attributes taxonomies:
foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $attribute ) {
    $term_names = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), $attribute, ['fields' => 'names'] );

    if( ! empty( $term_names ) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . wc_attribute_label($attribute) . ':</strong> ' . implode(', ', $term_names) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Tested and works.

Comment: thank you, but when I use `var_dump` to display the content of `$term_names` I get all  attributes of the current product in it. Because I'm using the slug, I use `wc_attribute_label($attribute)` to get the label of the attribute

Comment: Sorry, if that wasn't clear enough. And of course, I want to show all term names of an attribute used in the product. And only the attributes I select in the array. But at the moment `$term_names` shows every attribute with all its content (multiple `object(WC_Product_Attribute`) if that makes any sense

Comment: Again thank you! But now I get an error in the array: `["invalid_taxonomy"]` :-(

Comment: Ah ok, I need to change `'pa_'.$attribute` to `$attribute`

Comment: Thanks again! Great stuff ;)